# Making extension to get chrome tabs and input them in a google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to start off by saying I'm an extreme novice to making extensions and such. I wanted to make an extension that takes either pages visited or tabs opened and inputs them into a google docs spreadsheet. I've been scratching my head for days at this and googling things but I can never get it to work for me. I've tried using forms, spreadsheets, etc. I just would like a spreadsheet that I can view the pages I visit and how many times I visit them, so I can see my most visited page over a span of a month, along with all other pages I have visited.

I'm using Google Chrome and this is the current background.js code of the extension:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(info) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=Keygoeshere";
  req.open("POST", url, true);
  chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId,function(tab){
    var params = "entry.0.single=" + info.url + "&entry.1.single=" + tab.title; 
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send(params);
  });
},
{ urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"]});
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what exactly didn't work for you, but my answer posted below isn't affected by that - I believe you've been trying to apply wrong technologies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making up a way to post rows into a spreadsheet. Where did you get that such way will work? You need to look at the google spreadsheet api to understand how to append a row. Other than that I think its fine and useful to see chrome history in w spreadsheet. Another answer mentions history api but that's not a replacement since you would still need to open the extension to view your local history. By using a spreadsheet you can merge all your devices histories plus view them from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the [Chrome Extensions History API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history). You can either return the information in bulk using `search()` method, or listen to the `onVisit` event to receive real-time notifications about each visit. In both cases, you will have access to the number of visits, the way the URL is accessed (typed, clicked, etc.), and so on. With `search()`, you can also limit the timeframe you want to look at, as well as specify a free-form search string to filter your results.

The only thing you will have left to do is format this information into a nice HTML table with clickable links - no Google docs spreadsheet needed.